# script/server is not working. When the command is executed, it is showing the following error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
/home/vinay/mynewapp/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21:in `add_frozen_gem_path': undefined method `source_index' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /home/vinay/mynewapp/config/boot.rb:47:in `load_initializer'
    from /home/vinay/mynewapp/config/boot.rb:38:in `run'
    from /home/vinay/mynewapp/config/boot.rb:11:in `boot!'
    from /home/vinay/mynewapp/config/boot.rb:114:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from script/server:2:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What version of rails are you using? `script/server` is for rails 2. `rails server` is for rails 3.

Comment: Why do people vote down when they dont even know the user using rails2 or rails3!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `rails server` instead?

Shorter versions: `rails s` or even `r s`